# Passing parameter in backbone and require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

How would I pass a variable to the function in a view file ? Following is my call function in the controller. I have added the view file in the path earlier in the code.

```
app.region.show(new view({templatePath:'app\view\MyView.tpl'});
```

and here is the view file in which I want like the variable appear. Something like option in Backbone. One ugly way I can think is to attached the variable to app object but will hate to do that for obvious reasons.

```
define(["app"], function(app) {
  require([templatePath], function(someTplFile){
    MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: someTplFile
    });
  });  
  return MyView;
});
```

Help Appreciated.

*** Adding Edit for pkyeck comment****

This will not work ....

```
contentMain = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function(values) {
      require([values.tplName], function(mainTpl){
        this.var1 = mainTpl;
      });  
    },

    template: this.var1,
  });
```

Comment: put the `require` inside the view-class constructor this way you could access the passed variable `templatePath`.

Comment: This will not work ....

'contentMain = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function(values) {
      require([values.tplName], function(mainTpl){
        this.var1 = mainTpl;
      });  
    },

    template: this.var1,
  });'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you pass to the view is accesible in the initialization of the view. Here you can save the attributes to the view.

Something like this:

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function(values) {
        this.templatePath = values.templatePath;
    },

    anotherFunction : function(){
        //this.templatePath can be read here
    }
});

app.region.show(new view({templatePath:'app\view\MyView.tpl'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with following solution ....

```
  require(["app\view\MyView.tpl"], function(viewTpl){
    app.region.show(new contentView.contentMain({template:viewTpl}));      
  });
```

in view file ...

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
 initialize: function(values) {
   this.var1 = values.template;
 },

 template: this.var1
});
```

Thank you for the help